# Showing two model in same page Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have two models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
title= models.CharField(max_length=255)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
body = models.TextField()
postimage = models.ImageField(null= True, blank= True, upload_to="images/")
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)


def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title + " | "+ str(self.author)
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('article_deatil', args=(str(self.id)))


class AboutMe(models.Model):
title1= models.CharField(max_length=255, default="About Me")
body = models.TextField()
skill1= models.CharField(max_length=255)
skill1body = models.TextField()
skill2= models.CharField(max_length=255)
skill2body = models.TextField()
skill3= models.CharField(max_length=255)
skill3body = models.TextField()
edu1=models.CharField(max_length=255)
edu1body =  models.TextField()
edu2=models.CharField(max_length=255)
edu2body =  models.TextField()
edu3=models.CharField(max_length=255)
edu3body = models.TextField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title1
```

I want to show both of them in my home.html

```
class HomeView(ListView):
model = Post
template_name = 'home.html'
queryset = Post.objects.order_by('-published_date')[:3]
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('',HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),
path('',PostViewList.as_view(), name="postlist"),
```

]

I'm new to django and not sure how to show case two model in one template. I did put the post.body and other tags in my html but it not showing the About me part.

Comment: How is `AboutMe` linked to a user?

Comment: it's not connected. I just wanted the admin be able to add the about me. I'm just trying to create a weblog ^^"  should it be linked to a user
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want one more queryset of `AboutMe` model like `Post` model.

You should simply use [`get_context_data()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data) in the following way:

```py
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'
    queryset = Post.objects.order_by('-published_date')[:3]

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['about_me_records'] = AboutMe.objects.all()
        return context
```

Now, you have one more queryset `about_me_records` to use in the template and iterate over.

Comment: thank you so much. if I want to just show it one time, can I just use the model without iteration?

Comment: @FoxBlack I didn't understand, what do you want to show, can you explain more clearly?

Comment: sorry, I want to show the AboutMe model in the same page as the Post but I don't want to loop through it.

Comment: The key of your question is here: AboutMe.objects.all()

Comment: You should learn about  making queries https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/